# Module 'trace' has no attribute 'modname' while trying to debug in PyCharm (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, python-3.6

I have *Python 3.6rc1* installed from the [official "pkg" bundle](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360rc1/) for Mac OS. Now, every time I'm using a "debug" run configuration in PyCharm (does not depend on a particular script), I'm getting a huge stack trace with the following error messages (thrown multiple times in a row):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_signature.py", line 88, in create_signature
    filename, modulename, funcname = self.file_module_function_of(frame)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_signature.py", line 102, in file_module_function_of
    modulename = trace.modname(filename)
AttributeError: module 'trace' has no attribute 'modname'
```

Using the currently latest PyCharm 2016.3. Note that I can debug using Python 2.7 or 3.5 using the same PyCharm instance without any problems.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Is there a workaround?

---

<sup>Posting on SO since I'm not completely sure this is actually a bug or I've misconfigured something; plus, I know that PyCharm team checks the `pycharm` tag here; and, it would be easier for others to find this topic here as opposed to on the PyCharm's bug tracker.</sup>

Comment: Does your own project has a module named `trace`?

Comment: @yole from what I see, there is no `trace.py` or `trace` package in the project. But, you are on the right track - I cannot reproduce the problem in a brand new project. So, it has to do with what is inside the project, I'll investigate. Thanks!

Comment: happening to me too. Debug runs fine on 3.5.2 but fails with same error on python 3.6 using PyCharm 2016.3

Comment: @emepe thanks for the inspiration - mystery solved - please see the posted answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is actually a [bug](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/69) in the PyCharm's [`PyDev.Debugger`](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger), it uses the `trace.modname` which does not exist since Python 3.2:

```
def file_module_function_of(self, frame): #this code is take from trace module and fixed to work with new-style classes
    code = frame.f_code
    filename = code.co_filename
    if filename:
        modulename = trace.modname(filename)  # < HERE
    else:
        modulename = None
    # ...
```

Now, this particular code would only be executed if the debugger is started with the `--save-signatures` command-line option which is enabled by the "Collect run-time types information for code insight" Python debugger setting:

[image]

**Turn the setting off and the error would go away.**

Comment: I tried your workaround and it works! Also, I'm following your issue report at github. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @alecxe.